# Convert year and week number to date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using form elements to create a datepicker. You can either pick a year, a month and a day. Or you can pick a year and a week. I'm struggling with the week bit.

You select a start year and a start week and then an end year and an end week.

Let's say you pick 4 as the start week and 7 as the end week. I then want Monday week 4 as the start date and Sunday week 7 as the end date.

How do I get those dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD? Don't know where to start!

What I have now is four dropdown menus. Start year, start week, end year and end week. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many different ways to go about this problem. I started with asking myself, "How would I get the date given the day and month?", then I worked backwards from that, with given the week number, how to get the date. The answer is pretty straight forward and involves a double `For` loop and the use of [Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.weeknum) in VBA. Setting the start of week to Monday will also return the Monday of that given week so no extra effort is required for that.

```vb
Sub Convert_Dates()

    'user inputs
    Dim lYear As Long: lYear = 2020
    Dim lWeekNum As Long: lWeekNum = 4


    Dim lMonth As Long, lDay As Long


    For lMonth = 1 To 12
        For lDay = 1 To 31
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateSerial(lYear, lMonth, lDay), vbMonday) = lWeekNum Then
                Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(lYear, lMonth, lDay), "YYYY-MM-DD")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next lDay
    Next lMonth

End Sub
```

And the output is:

[image]

I am sure you can now modify this to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you! That was so simple! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Jens if this answers your question, please can you mark it as the answer to close it. Cheers